# session сбрасывается после перезапуска браузера (моб) php

Tags: php, сессия

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код авторизации на сайте.

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");

if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['login'])) {

    $query  = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='".$_POST['password']."' AND login='".$_POST['login']."' LIMIT 1;", mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']));
    mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row                 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
    }
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
// Показываем окно авторизации
}
else {
// Личный кабинет
}
?>
```

Но при перезапуске мобильного браузера опять запрашивает окно авторизации.
В чем может быть проблема?
В десктопной версии все нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для себя нашел такой вариант.

```
$lifetime = 3600;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
session_start();
```

Comment: Не забудьте пройтись по всем остальным настройкам сессий. В частности gc_maxlifetime. save_path, save_handler и проверить, что за уборку мусора отвечает сам PHP, а не отдельный скрипт, как например, в дефолтной настройки ubuntu и debian.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, ответ-не ответ, но в комментах писать несподручно. Что может быть(имхо):

1. Нет увязки по сессиям с мобильной версией
2. Настройка мобильного браузера удаляет все при перезапуске - куки/сессии и прочее.

Попробуйте авторизоваться в мобильной и затем перезапустить браузер - если слетит, значит, весьма вероятен затык с этой стороны.

Да - и непонятно из Вашей информации - у Вас отдельная моб версия сайта, или адаптив?

Если адаптив, то скорее всего именно браузер, поскольку все остается, только вид меняется - при обычном варианте, конечно.

Comment: Адаптивная версия сайта. Все равно не могу понять в чем может быть проблема. На всех мобильных браузерах слетает авторизация.

Comment: Проверьте наличие сессионной переменной в мобильной версии - если есть, то блок проверки ее наличия глючит при переходе на мобильные варианты.

Comment: Сессионная переменная есть, но после перезагрузки браузера меняется.

Comment: Ну вот - посмотрите, почему - наверное, есть что-то с одинаковым именем либо перезаписывается, поскольку не находит сохраненной user_id

Answer (score 1):

Механизм сессий PHP не живёт без куки с id сессии (ну, вообще-то живёт, но тогда sid должен быть настроен передаваться через GET параметры).

Кука эта выставляется со временем жизни [`session.cookie_lifetime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime). Настройка по-умолчанию - 0. Что предполагает:

> The value 0 means "until the browser is closed."

Значение 0 означает "пока браузер не будет закрыт". Некоторые браузеры согласны с такой трактовкой, некоторые нет.

Поэтому наблюдаемое различие поведения является нормой и никакой проблемы нет. Так задумано разработчиками проверенных вами браузеров.

Comment: На сервере session.cookie_lifetime равен 0. Подскажите тогда куда копать что бы после перезапуска браузера авторизация не слетала (установить lifetime не получиться).

Comment: Прочитайте мой ответ ещё раз. Так и задумано.

Comment: Пусть так и задумано но взять любой сайт, после перезапуска браузера авторизация не слетит.

Comment: Вот и описывайте и решайте основную задачу. Долговременная авторизация просто не делается через сессии. Это параллельный механизм. А чтобы авторизация долговременно жила на сессиях - там много настроек править надо. И всё равно ловить костыли и грабли. Потому что инструмент не тот.

Comment: Подскажите что лучше использовать для долговременных авторизаций.

Comment: Кука с криптографически-стойким токеном авторизации. По ней авторизуете и при необходимости стартуете короткоживущую сессию.